# VB.NET Update to Excel

Tags: vb.net

I am developing an application in Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2013.  In this application I am attempting to use an oledb UPDATE to write data out to an Excel spreadsheet treated as a database.  I have tried numerous different formats of this but I either get a syntax error or it pretends to work but nothing actually gets written to the file.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code:

Public Function WriteToExcel(ExcelPath As String, dtUser As DataTable)

```
    Dim vOffice As String = dtUser.Rows(0).Item("Office").ToString
    Dim vDivision As String = dtUser.Rows(0).Item("Division").ToString
    Dim vSection As String = dtUser.Rows(0).Item("Section").ToString
    Dim vUser As String = dtUser.Rows(0).Item("UserID").ToString

    Dim ExcelconnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ExcelPath & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
    Dim BatchID As Long = 0
    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE [InstallationReport$] SET Office = @uOffice WHERE [Primary User] = @uUser"
    'Dim sql As String = "UPDATE [InstallationReport$] SET Office = @uOffice, " & _
    '"Division = @uDivision, " & _
    '"Section = @uSection " & _
    '"WHERE [Primary User] = @uUser"

    Using conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ExcelconnString)
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uOffice", vOffice)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uDivision", vDivision)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uSection", vSection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uUser", vUser)

        Try
            MessageBox.Show("Attempting to update " & vUser & ". " & vOffice & ", " & vDivision & ", " & vSection & "!")
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbNewLine & ex.StackTrace)

        End Try

    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but [OleDbCommands use question marks as the placeholder for parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), not `@parameterName` (that's for SqlCommands).

Comment: @Heinzi  Thank you.  That worked for updating a single column.  Now when I try to expand that out to update three columns, I get a syntax error.  The line reads:   Dim sql As String = "UPDATE [InstallationReport$] SET Office = ?, Division = ?, Section = ? WHERE [Primary User] = ?"  Everything I read says to use a comma as a separator.  Should I be using something else?

Comment: Your SQL looks fine. What exact error message do you get? Are you able to update only two of the three fields? Please try all combinations (Office+Division, Division+Section, Office+Section) and report back.

Comment: @Heinzi  Any combination that includes Section = ? gives the exact same error "Syntax Error in UPDATE statement."  No indication as to what the syntax error is.  I also tried to break it down into three separate OleDb commands and the Office and Division commands work just fine but the Section command produces the same syntax error.  Section isn't a reserved word by chance is it?

Comment: @Heinzi  Treated it like a reserved word and it works fine.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great, good catch! Glad I could help. I found a list of reserved keywords and summarized the result in an answer, so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL has two issues:

- [OleDbCommands use question marks `?` as the placeholder for parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), not `@parameterName` (that's for SqlCommands).
- `Section` [is a reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266/), so it needs to be escaped: `[Section]`.